# Android Publishing taking a long time

Tags: android, publish

I've published my Android app over two hours ago and it's still not published, my other App was published within a hour.

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal, There's a caching system in Google that runs every X hours, you might have uploaded your other app right before the Caching cycle.

Comment: Ok, I'm just hoping it goes live soon. I'm anxious to see the reposes and I want to see if deploying Admob would be a good idea.

Comment: Yeah BlueCat my last app took 4 hours to upload and congrats on publishing the app.